# Graph with path of length $\geq n$ along grid diagonals - a known result in graph theory?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, graph-theory, discrete-geometry, random-graphs

[image]

Is the following lemma a well known result in graph theory?

I am studying a basic existence result that appears to be simple yet powerful. I have not seen it stated as an important result in graph theory. I have consulted Reinhard Diestel's "Graph Theory" (5th edition, 2017), but could not find it there. So I wanted to ask this question on MO:

**Definition:** Given an $n\times n$ grid with $n^2$ unit squares. If you randomly place exactly 1 diagonal in each unit square, these diagonals (together with the vertices of the grid) form a graph $G$.

**Existence Lemma:**  $G$ always contains a path of length $\geq n$.

Above you can see a small example on a $6\times 6$ grid. There is a great graphical example for large $n$ by Joseph O’Rourke https://mathoverflow.net/a/112090/156936

I would be grateful if you could let me know whether this is a well known result, specifically in graph theory.

Is there maybe some more general result from graph theory that implies this particular case? I would be very interested in that.

Comment: In the previous thread, they show there is a path from one side to the other (that was exactly the question). Doesn't that imply your result?

Comment: Well there's a few proofs in that thread so surely, by definition, that means it's a known result?

Comment: @verret, thank you for your comment. Yes this lemma follows directly from the existence of such a crossing along diagonals. Maybe I should clarify this more explicitly. However, the other thread does not link this important result to graph theory. So my question is really whether this is a known result in graph theory? Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Is your question if there is some more general result from graph theory that implies this particular case?

Comment: @SamHopkins, yes this is exactly right. Thank you for this comment. I will articulate it this way in the question. I consider it to be a simple yet powerful result. That’s why I wonder where is its place in graph theory. Thanks again for your comment

Comment: Related connections to First- and Last-Passage Percolation at this MO question: [Shortest grid-graph paths with random diagonal shortcuts](https://mathoverflow.net/q/45920/6094).

Comment: @Joseph O' Rourke, thanks a lot for adding this link! I find it striking that this grid-graph model has so many facets and applications. Just in case if you have not yet seen, in this proof it is actually shown to be equivalent (!) to a separation theorem from topological dimension theory.  https://mathoverflow.net/a/360708/156936

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, and here is the second part of the equivalence proof https://mathoverflow.net/a/360623/156936

Comment: My guess is that the closest "quotable result" to this is the so-called "Hex theorem" that Hex cannot end in a draw. I think this is due to Gale but you can also read about it [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.7890). The Hex theorem does not immediately imply this result but it uses the same ideas. It does seem that there ought to be a more general theorem about planar graphs that includes this theorem and the Hex theorem as special cases, but I am not aware that anyone has stated such a result explicitly.

Comment: @TimothyChow, Thanks a lot for your comment! Very much appreciated. I think you are right that Game of Hex and this Grid-Path Lemma stand on the same ground (Hex can be proved by Brouwer FPT and the Grid-Path Lemma can be proved by Sperner’s Lemma). The striking thing is that this Grid-Path Lemma seems so fundamental and I wonder where is its place in graph theory? I did quite some research but could not find it. Thanks a lot for your suggestion to look deeper into planar graph theory, maybe this is the right way forward.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Joseph I just wanted to share with you, in case you are interested in this: a nice proof from user Oliver Clarke that there is more than 1 crossing path (along diagonals in the grid) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3689297/782412

Comment: @TimothyChow Timothy I just wanted to share with you, in case you are interested in this: a nice proof from user Oliver Clarke that there is more than 1 crossing path (along diagonals in the grid) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3689297/782412

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Timothy Chow's comment is right that there is no result about planar graphs with your lemma as an explicit corollary.

I believe the following 2007 research paper by Guido Helden might be of use to you: http://publications.rwth-aachen.de/record/62349/ It is about hamiltonicity of maximal planar graphs and planar triangulations, and starts with a very good exposition.

Comment: thanks a lot for this link! I am very interested in it and will definitely take a look