# Diagonal shortcuts to minimize all-pairs shortest-paths in grid graph

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry

Augment the grid graph $G$ on lattice points $[1,n]^2$, which
connects each point to its four distance-$1$ vertical and horizontal neighbors.
Augment $G$ to $G'$ by adding in one of the two $\sqrt{2}$ diagonals
to each $1 \times 1$ lattice square.
I am seeking to understand which selection of diagonal shortcuts will minimize the total length
of all shortest paths:
all shortest paths between the $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of lattice points
in the augmented graph $G'$.
An example $G'$ is shown below.

---

[image: Grid_7x7]

          

<sup>$n=7$.</sup>

---

Above the shortest path from $(1,1)$ to $(7,7)$ is $4+4\sqrt{2} \approx 9.7$,
while the shortest path from $(7,1)$ to $(1,7)$ is $6\sqrt{2} \approx 8.5$.

> ***Q***. What is the optimal choice of diagonals to minimize the sum of the lengths
>   of the shortest paths in $G'$  between all pairs of lattice points, for
>   arbitrary $n$?

Perhaps this has been studied before?
It seems related to [shortest-path trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest-path_tree),
but I am not seeing how that concept yields the optimal network in the described situation.

---

Related: [Shortest grid-graph paths with random diagonal shortcuts](https://mathoverflow.net/q/45920/6094).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkerboard pattern is optimal, as long as the top left corner (or, indeed, at least one corner) has an adjacent diagonal.

[image]

Observe that the smallest possible distance between opposite corners of an $h \times w$ rectangle in any diagonal orientation is $h + w - (\sqrt{2} - 1)\cdot \min(h, w)$. One can see further that the checkerboard pattern achieves this bound for all rectangles with $h \neq w$, and is short $\sqrt{2} - 1$ to achieve it for about half of square corner pairs. Let us show that no orientation can do better than that.

A corner pair of a square is at optimum distance iff it is connected by an unbroken chain of diagonals. Consider any square with odd side length $k$; clearly, at most one of its diagonals can be unbroken. Hence, there can be at most $(n - k)^2$ optimum corner pairs, a bound that checkerboard readily achieves.

Squares with even side length $k$ require a bit more thought. Let's choose one of two diagonals in each $k \times k$ so that adjacent (= different by a shift of distance 1) squares have different orientations. There are two ways to do that, take any one of them.

[image]

Observe that in any pair of adjacent squares, at most one can have an unbroken diagonal of the chosen type. It follows that among the chosen diagonals at most $\lceil (n - k)^2 / 2 \rceil$ can be unbroken (since this is the maximum size of an independent set in an $(n - k) \times (n - k)$ grid). Accounting for two ways to choose orientation, there can be at most $2 \lceil (n - k)^2 / 2 \rceil$ optimal corner pairs in $k \times k$ squares. With a little case work, one can see that this is exactly how many optimal pairs of this kind a checkerboard pattern has.

The same argument seems to apply for $n \times m$ rectangular grids as well as square ones.

Comment: Is your intention to create the checkerboard pattern on the even lattice points, and leave the odd lattice points inside each square, not incident to any diagonal? Thanks.

Comment: By checkerboard pattern I mean choosing orientation of each diagonal depending on the color of the square containing it (probably the same as your second option).